# Cambria Math becomes plain Cambria

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

I'm a LaTeX neophyte, so please excuse my ignorance.

I want to typeset a document with text in Cambria and math in Cambria Math.
I found the unicode-math package, which seems to do what I want.

Here is a simple sample:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}

The Bezier curve $C$ of degree $m$ is
$$C(u) = \sum_{i=0}^m f_i(u)P_i$$

\end{document}
```

The math is coming out as plain (upright) Cambria.

Any idea what might be going wrong ??

[Elaboration]: I'm using MikTeX 2.9, and XeLateX. I updated the XeTeX version because unicode-math told me to. I'm just choosing an option from the TeXworks menu. I don't know what's happening behind the scenes (and I hope I don't need to know).

Here is some log file output that might be relevant:

```
Requested font "Cambria/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Windows/Fonts/CAMBRIA.TTC
Requested font "Cambria Math/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Windows/Fonts/CAMBRIA.TTC
\g_fontspec_family_Cambria Math_int=\count125
Requested font "Cambria Math/B/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Windows/Fonts/CAMBRIA.TTC
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-font-shape"
. 
. Could not resolve font Cambria Math/B (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'CambriaMath(0)' created for font 'Cambria Math' with options
. [BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=10-},{Size=7
-10,Font=Cambria
. Math,Style=MathScript},{Size=-7,Font=Cambria
. Math,Style=MathScriptScript}},].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <10->"Cambria Math/ICU:script=math;language=DFLT;"<7-10>"Cambria
. Math/ICU:script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=0;"<-7>"Cambria
. Math/ICU:script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=1;"
```

Comment: Unrelated comment: you shouldn't use `$$ .. $$`, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Works fine for me with XeLaTeX and Lualatex (miktex 2.9). How are you compiling and what is your TeX-System?

Comment: Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to your document and compile on the command line with the option `--output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv"`. Put the log-file somewhere for download and show (copy&paste) the messages of xdvipdfmx in the terminal.

Comment: I didn't wrote "show a snippet from your log". To make a diff with my log file I need the complete log-file. And I need the messages from `xdvipdfmx`. It would also be a good idea if you could put the pdf somewhere for download.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This behaviour is due to a known 'breaking' change in the latest `l3kernel` release (*i.e.* one which the team knew altered behaviour but which was felt was the best choice in the long term). As such, `unicode-math` needs to be updated to conform with the altered `l3kernel` code.

---

Temporary fix (use at own risk): Make a *copy* of `unicode-math.sty` in your local tree and do a search-and-replace for `\l_keys_choice_int`, replacing with `\l_keys_choice_int \or`. That will fix the issue *until* `unicode-math` is fixed officially. (At least it does in my quick tests.)

---

The fixed `unicode-math` is now available on CTAN and in TeX Live 2012. As anticipated, this deals with the issue and all is well again.

Comment: I will edit here once the fix is sent to CTAN: I'm going to sort out the appropriate bits and pieces and talk with Will Robertson.

Comment: BTW, I have logged this as an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/242), so people can track what is happening.

Comment: Dammit, sorry about this — all my fault. Will fix ASAP (likely tonight).

Comment: Should be fixed now; not sure when the update will propagate to TL.