# Get back "old" math font in LuaLaTeX+beamer

Tags: beamer, luatex, unicode-math

Updated my tlmgr install (and all packages I have installed today) earlier today, and something changed in the font loaded by `unicode-math`, which I can't figure out of.

The preamble I've been using for making the `beamer` presentations is as below:

```
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}
\documentclass[smaller]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\mode<presentation>{%
    \AtBeginSection{%
        }
\useoutertheme[nofootline]{wuerzburg}
\useinnertheme[outline,shadow]{chamfered}
\usecolortheme{shark}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{fontspec,microtype,amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
```

Before updating, the font resembled:

[image]

After the update, the font resembled:

[image]

As I haven't changed anything at all in the preamble, I have to assume that one of the packages I use was updated (but since I didn't pay attention to the command line window I'm not sure of which).

I've tried to load `unicode-math` with the options `math-style=TeX` and `math-style=ISO` without any luck. Also tried to remove `fontspec`, `microtype`, and `amsmath`, but still the same.

Any input on how to get the font to be as it was before the update?

Comment: There is an issue at present due to a mismatch between `unicode-math` and it's support packages: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=unicode-math. This could be the same thing.

Comment: Not sure if I'm experienced enough to tell if its the same thing or not. But think I'll try to downgrade to a previous version of the package if I can find one anywhere. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ok, definitely the same issue. If you post it as an answer I can accept it and close this question. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue at present due to a mismatch between `unicode-math` and it's support packages: see [Cambria Math becomes plain Cambria](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/cambria-math-becomes-plain-cambria) and [7-2012 l3kernel & l3packages updates | 'broken'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64663/7-2012-l3kernel-l3packages-updates-broken). The code has been updated, and I would expect this to make its way into TeX Live and MiKTeX over the next few days.

Comment: Should now be fixed: try updating your TeX system.