# Unicode-math math-style does not work for Latin capitals and Greek

Tags: unicode-math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cambria Math becomes plain Cambria](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/cambria-math-becomes-plain-cambria)

Table 3, pg. 7 of the unicode-math documentation says:

> math-style=ISO (, , , ) (, , , )

But when I use ISO option with the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
 $A=c+d = a+\beta$
\end{document}
```

I get the Latin captital A and Greek β both upright chatacters. What gives?
I just updated the package as well.

Comment: Make sure that you really have the newest version ( [2012/07/28 v0.7a Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX]).

Comment: Oh thanks it works after I refresh the DB and restarted the editor after the update.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/cambria-math-becomes-plain-cambria: this looks like the same issue.

Comment: Same issue as my link, and sorted by an update, so could be 'too localized' or 'exact duplicate'. I've gone for the latter, as this way there is a 'trail' back to a single question covering the problem.